# Angular Rest call immediately fails but does not make call

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs

My intention is to make a REST call to a backend service.  On the initial page load the call enters the failure lambda. The browser network section indicates no service call was made.  If I refresh the page, it makes the call.

I can't show the full source, but here's a portion of what I have below. When the page is first loaded, the console log messages are in order:

```
@@BP1
@@BP3
```

I tried calling a different service in hub.service before the hub summary service, and it worked as expected.

To be clear, I would understand reaching an error if the framework actually made the HTTP REST call, but it did not. The error instead was something like "TypeError: value is null"

homepage-hub-summary-tile-component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hub } from '../../../hub.service';
import { ReportService } from '../../../report.service';
import { HubSummaryTileData, LoadStatus } from '../../../model/hub.summary.tile.data'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage-hub-summary-tile',
  templateUrl: './homepage-hub-summary-tile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage-hub-summary-tile.component.css']
})
export class HomepageHubSummaryTileComponent implements OnInit {
  LoadStatusType = LoadStatus;
  tileLoadStatus: LoadStatus = LoadStatus.STARTING;
  constructor(private hubService: HubService,private reportService : ReportService) {
      //this.popupHomeFilterSelection = this.reportService.getPopupHomeFilterSelection();
      this.popupHomeFilterSelection = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSummaryTileData();

  }

  getSummaryTileData() {
    this.tileLoadStatus = LoadStatus.LOADING;
    this.hubService.getHubSummaryTileData()
      .subscribe((data ) =>
        {
          console.log('@@BP1');
          if(data ) {
            this.summaryTileData = data as unknown as HubSummaryTileData;
            this.tileLoadStatus = LoadStatus.SUCCESS;
            console.log('@@BP2');
          } else {
            this.tileLoadStatus = LoadStatus.ERROR;
            console.error('Error in data received from hub summary tile data');
            console.log('@@BP3');
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("@BP5");
          this.tileLoadStatus = LoadStatus.ERROR;
          console.log('Error fetching hub portfolio summary tile data: '+error)
        }
      );
      console.log("@BP6");


  }

}
```

hub.service.ts

```
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpEvent
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Injectable,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {
  AppConstant
} from './constants/app-constants';
import {
  Subscription
} from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';
import { UUID } from 'angular2-uuid';

import { HubSummaryTileData } from './model/hub.summary.tile.data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HubService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  private httpOptions : any = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Accept-Encoding', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
      .set('AUTH_USER', sessionStorage.getItem("authUser"))
      .set('ROLE_ID', sessionStorage.getItem("userRoleId"))
      .set('SC_TRACE_ID',UUID.UUID())

  };

  public getHubSummaryTileData() {
    return this.http.get<HubSummaryTileData>(AppConstant.URL_GET_HUB_SUMMARY_TILE_DATA,
      this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

If you read this far, thank you from the Woodsman.

Comment: I don't see HubService being injected into the constructor of `HomepageHubSummaryTileComponent` - did you simply not include that?

Comment: @dmcgrandle In the constructor, I had private hubPortfolioService: HubPortfolioService.  I realize it's not spelled correctly, but I changed some things to help obfusicate for intellectual property reasons (probably doesn't matter much). Anyway, I thought that passing in the private HubPortfolioService (which is really HubService), is injecting it.  I'm really new to Angular and even Node, sorry to ask a rudimentary question.

Comment: Yes, if you define the service as `Injectable` and put it in the constructor, Angular will indeed inject that dependency.  There is nothing glaringly obvious in the code you have provided.  Could you create an example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) so we can see the issue first-hand?

Comment: I found the problem was that the sessionStorage.getItem returned null due to the call not having been set first.  Despite the service being provided in the constructor, it did not require that call to have been executed first.  I fixed the problem by forcing the code that gets the authUser and userRoleId to be executed first, then stored in the session storage.